# Fundamental group of these two spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Consider the spaces shown in the following pictures. The one on the left is the unit circle union with a line segment, and the one on the right is the same but with the point $(2,0)$ removed from the line segment.

I am trying to find the fundamental group of these two spaces using deformation retracts. Any hints please?

[image]

Comment: Retract the line segments to the circles. What shapes are you left with?

Comment: @CyclotomicField A circle in both cases?

Comment: No, it's not a circle in both cases.

Comment: @CyclotomicField But in both cases all the points of the line segments are collapsed to the point $(1,0)$.

Comment: My mistake, they are both circles. I thought the missing point was another circle so that it would be the wedge sum of two circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you get the unit circle $S^1$ as a strong deformation retract. In fact, $S^1$ is a strong deformation retract of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ via
$$H : (\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}) \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}, H(x,t) = (1-t)x + t \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert} .$$
Restricting $H$ to each of your spaces $X_i$ gives homotopies taking place inside $X_i$ which shows that $S^1$ is a strong deformation retract of $X_i$.

Thus the fundamental group of both spaces is $\mathbb Z$.